# Redirect to subdir (using extract from REQUEST_URI and perdir)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I usually use the following .htaccess to map nonexistant urls to index.php:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=REWRITE_BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITE_BASE}index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

This allows me to have a dynamic rewritebase.

However, right now I'm trying to modify this `.htaccess` so I can redirect all requests to a subdir, but right now all requests are going to `index_dev.php`, even existing files... The following is what I have currently:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::(\2)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=REWRITE_BASE:%1]

# modify request_filename
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*?)(/web)*(/.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=WEB_REQUEST_FILENAME:%1/web%3]

# If file exists under web / redirect it
RewriteCond %{ENV:WEB_REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITE_BASE}web/$1 [QSA,L]

# If file doesn't exist, redirect to web/index_dev.php.
RewriteCond %{ENV:WEB_REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{ENV:WEB_REQUEST_FILENAME} !/web/index_dev.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITE_BASE}web/index_dev.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I have my files layed out in the following matter:

```
<root>
|   .htaccess
|   web
|   |   index_dev.php
|   |   js
|   |   |   website.js
|   src
|   |   (PHP Files)
|   vendor
|   |   (PHP Files)
```

I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest keeping it simple and have your .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=REWRITE_BASE:%1]

# If file exists under web / redirect it
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{ENV:REWRITE_BASE}web/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]

# If file doesn't exist, redirect to web/index_dev.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?!web/index_dev\.php).*)$ web/index_dev.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but most of the projects require that I use a subdirectory ( in particular, it's a staging area like /projects/<someproject_name>/) and we use git to commit code so I can't really use this code.

Comment: ok check updated answer, which will work from any sub-directory as well.